# JsHint error using Underscore and Google Maps in Angular services

Tags: javascript, angularjs, google-maps, underscore.js, mean

I'm using [mean.js](http://meanjs.org/) and I loaded both Underscore (via static file) and Google Maps (from their cdn).

I'm using those in a service but as soon as I save the file I'm working on I receive this error from JsHint:

`^ '_' is not defined.`

and

`^ 'google' is not defined.`

Both are working fine but I wish to don't see this error, how can I solve it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to set global variables for '_' and 'google' to prevent the error. One way to do this is to add them at the top of the script file. e.g:

```
/*global _:false */
```

or you can create a .jshintrc file in the root of your project, and the global variable in there e.g.:

```
"globals": {
    "_":false,
    "google":false
  }
```

Comment: Well, it solves the problem because I'm gonna say to `jsHint` to don't "watch" for `_` and `google`, but I was looking more to solve it from Angular side...

Comment: @AyeyeBrazo As far as I know there is no special way of solving the issue for Angular.  I've always used the /*global _:false */ at the top of each of my script files. If someone out there does know a special Angular way, I'd be interested to know about it too....